# PeopleSoft Payroll Interface Field length

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

I have added a field to a Payroll Interface definition. I am using the delivered field TEXT254.  The field where you define the length of the field in bytes (field definition table) is three characters, so it would *appear* that you can define the length as 999 bytes.  The PI process fails when I set the length to 999 bytes, until I lowered it to 150 bytes.  I am experimenting, with it, slowly increasing the value I'm wondering if anyone knows what the limit really is?  Our PI takes 3 hours to run, so experimenting takes a long time.

edit - I cut down the runtime by getting rid of all but one company.  The largest byte size that I seem to be able to get to run is 240.  I did some research, and it looks like when you build your tables, Oracle will set the field to VARCHAR2(n*3) where n is the size of the field specified in AppDesigner.  Sure enough, the script generated by the Project...Build sets my field to VARCHAR2(762).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found - the data that the PI exports is pretty much unlimited - in the PI_PARTIC_EXPT table, the EXPORT_ROW field is 250 characters.  If the row you're exporting exceeds this, a new row is inserted with a new sequence number (export_seq), and the data is continued in the EXPORT_ROW field in this new row.

There is,however, a limit to an idividual field that the PI can handle, and that is 240 characters, so once I limited the field to 240 characters all was well.